How do we check if workflow manager service is running programmatically in SharePoint Subscription Edition on-premise?
We have SharePoint Subscription Edition instance on-premise.
Often we find the the workflow manager service is down and that causes attached workflows to fail and to be restarted.
We would like to check programmatically (C#) if work flow service is down and raise an alert.
Is that possible?
